# How to sum different columns from one table and get the sum result in another table using PHP or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Below is the tables example:

```
stock_entries as table 1 
stockid  supplier    item    total   payment   balance
   1      john      iphone    100      10        90
   2     charles     itel      50      40        10
   3      john       ipad     500     250       250
   4      alex      tecno      20      20         0
   5     charles    ipad       30      0         30

supplier_details as table 2
number    supplier    contact    total_balance
  1        alex       0843433         ?
  2       charles     7784336         ?
  3        john      21184584         ?
```

I want to sum balance column from `stock_entries` table for each supplier and get the result in `supplier_details` table under the column `total_balance`.
For instance, to get `total_balance` for john, the system will automatically check the `balance column` from `stock_entries` table where supplier name is john and sum the balance found for john and put the result as `total_balance` in `supplier_details` table.

I want it perform something like this from stock_entries table, john: 90+250=380 where 380= total_balance which will go to total_balance column in supplier_detail. the same thing for the other suppliers.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like:

```
insert into table2 (field1, field2) 
   select sum(whatever), otherfield 
   from table1 
   where otherfield in('val1', 'val2')
   group by otherfield ;
```

Comment: could you please use the two tables info in the sql statement so as i will understand well

Comment: @Dalhat, I'm not doing the work for you, just showing you the syntax to do it.